# External JavaScript Files will not execute in IE9

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

The following is a snippit from my a little web page I'm putting together.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="head.js">

</script>
<title>CPST 3410-85 Class Template</title>
</head>

<body onload="outputToDiv();">
```

The head.js file referenced in the script tag is below:

```
function outputToDiv() {
alert("JavaScript is working!");
}
```

In Chrome and in Firefox the alert is displayed indicating the JavaScript is working.  In IE9 it is not.  Furtermore I can't get ANY external script to run in IE9, regardless of the content.  I have used custom security settings and lowered in a granular way every security setting to its lowest level, and gone into advanced settings and enabled literally everything I could find.

It should be noted that I am opening this from a local folder.  All files are in the same folder, and again I stress that this works in firefox and chrome.

In IE9 I have enabled debugging and I get the error below:

Webpage error details

```
Message: Invalid character
Line: 1
Char: 1
Code: 0
URI: file:///E:/My%20Documents/My%20Web%20Sites/CPST341085/head.js
```

Of course it then tells me that "outputToDiv()" is undefined.

I am at a total loss here.

Comment: the first thing I notice is that the script tag dooesn't require a seperate closing tag. What happens if you remove the following line: </script>

Comment: @SteveRobillard: Uh, yes, `<script>` **does** require a separate closing tag.

Comment: @SteveRobillard Older versions of IE NEED a closing script tag.

Comment: Look at what is in the JS file in the built in debugger. Is it what you expect? You should also run a local server instead of using the file protocol.

Comment: Can you paste in the first few line of your head.js file?

Comment: JasCav the entire head.js file is contained in the question.  it's just an alert.  it was much more at one time, but I am just using an alert for now to troubleshoot.

Comment: I just created a sample head.js and a test.html file with your exact content. IE9 first asked me if I'd like to run ActiveX content. After I allowed it to run the content, it worked just fine. What happens if you move the JavaScript out of the external file?

Comment: It works fine if I use it internally.  It isn't asking me about activex content at all actually.

Comment: Also I've tried xhtml strict, transitional, and html 4.01 strict, and transitional.  So that didn't make any difference.

Comment: Can you upload that file to a server and request it from there? Perhaps your editor added a BOM or someting

Comment: I'm using expression web 4 (and 3 sometimes).  I've discovered that I can copy an existing working js file through the filesystem and reference it, and it works.  If I create a new .js file either through expression or through the file system and add it to exspression I get the invalid character error... ONLY in IE.

Answer (score 0):

I got this behavior when I had:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.1.js" />
```

However, this fixed it:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
```

Go figure...

David